# uri regex pattern match

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm having trouble getting urls to match with

```
 sregex rex = sregex::compile("(?:ftp|http|https)+://([\\S\^<\^>]+)", sregex::icase );
```

It matches all the urls but it also includes >> on the end of each match, which I'm trying to negate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you intend `[\\S\^<\^>]+` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is this:

```
 sregex rex = sregex::compile("(?:ftp|http|https)://([\\S]+[^<>]*)", sregex::icase );
```

The character `^` only means "not" when `^` is the first character of a set. Thus, the `^` in `[\\S\^<\^>]+` does not mean "not." When `^` is not the first character of a set, it indicates the [beginning of a target sequence or follows a line terminator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/), or has no special meaning.

Comment: Why does the capture group need a `+`?  (Or the protocol match for that matter?)

Comment: I wondered the same thing about the captured group, but left it since it was in the askers original.

Comment: Except the OP's was inside the capture group.

Comment: +1 Yes, after rereading, the OP appears to only be concerned with < or > at the end, so I have changed it again. Thanks.